# Android service doesn't restart

Tags: android, android-service, android-7.0-nougat, android-version

My service doesn't restart when app stoping. Where is my mistake ?
My Android version is 7.1.1 
I try thats;
I returned START_STICKY on the onStartCommand .
I write this method.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        Log.e("Tem Harita","Service Killed");
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
            restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());


            PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmService.set(
                    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3500,
                    restartServicePendingIntent);
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        }

    }
```

but it's sometimes work sometimes doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: sometimes question is a bit unclear

Comment: Yea , idk why it doesn't work. I just ask :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your phone
Setting->battery- >battery optimisation-> click on your app ->click dont optimise

You can do same for all apps